# when I am using Http proxy integration in aws api gateway is throwing a 500 internal server error with invalid endpoint address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, swagger, aws-api-gateway, http-proxy

My method in aws api gateway swagger is this authentication is working fine but it is failing to integrate with http backend

```
    "paths": {
        "/{eventtype}/{eventvalue}": {
          "put": {
            "summary": "Leap events Api",
            "description": "API to consume json payloads to further post on kafka topics",
            "consumes": [
              "application/json"
            ],
            "produces": [
              "application/json"
            ],
             "security":[{
                "sigv4": []
              }],
            "parameters": [

              {
                "in": "body",
                "name": "Payload",
                "description": "Payload",
                "required": true,
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object"
                }
              },
              {
                "in": "path",
                "name": "eventtype",
                "description": "",
                "type": "string",
                "required": true
              },
              {
                "in": "path",
                "name": "eventvalue",
                "description": "",
                "type": "string",
                "required": true
              },
              {
                "in": "query",
                "name": "program",
                "description": "",
                "type": "string",
                "required": true
              },
              {
                "in": "query",
                "name": "sequence",
                "description": "",
                "type": "integer",
                "required": true
              },
              {
                "in": "query",
                "name": "schemaVersion",
                "description": "",
                "type": "integer",
                "required": true
              },
                 {
                "in": "query",
                "name": "timestamp",
                "description": "",
                "type": "integer",
                "required": true
              }
            ],
              "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
              "requestParameters": {
                "integration.request.path.eventtype": "method.request.path.eventtype",
                "integration.request.path.eventvalue": "method.request.path.eventvalue",
                "integration.request.querystring.program": "method.request.querystring.program",
                "integration.request.querystring.timestamp": "method.request.querystring.timestamp",
                "integration.request.querystring.schemaVersion": "method.request.querystring.schemaVersion",
                "integration.request.querystring.sequence": "method.request.querystring.sequence"

              }, "responseParameters": {
                 "method.response.body": "integration.response.body"


              },
              "responses":{
              "default":{
                "statusCode": "200"}
                },
              "uri": "https://********/*****/{eventtype}/{eventvalue}",
              "responses": {
                "200": {
                  "statusCode": "200"
                },
                "202": {
                  "statusCode": "202"
                },
                "default": {
                  "statusCode": "400"
                }
              },


              "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
              "httpMethod": "PUT",
              "type": "http_proxy"
            },
            "responses": {
              "200": {
                "description": "OK",
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/ResponseUpdateputcall"
                }
              },
              "400": {
                "description": "Bad request."
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

THese are my cloud watch logs 
    22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Extended Request Id: P9kq_Eiso****wg=
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Verifying Usage Plan for request: 93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba. API Key: API Stage: d*****0/dev
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) API Key authorized because method 'PUT /{***}/{***}' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage drjkf6qg20/dev
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Starting execution for request: 93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) HTTP Method: PUT, Resource Path: /****/{****}/{**}
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Method request path: {eventvalue=**, eventtype=***}
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Method request query string: {program=workkeys, schemaVersion=2.0, sequence=1.0, timestamp=1531851240}
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Method request headers: {X-Amz-Date=20181106T225203Z, Accept=*/*, User-Agent=PostmanRuntime/7.2.0, X-Forwarded-Proto=https, X-Forwarded-For=151.148.122.100, Host=api5-dev.act.org, Postman-Token=8696c60a-bf2d-4edd-9bb4-e55287c3efae, cache-control=no-cache, X-Forwarded-Port=443, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5be21b13-26a69774cca2073096ea
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Method request body before transformations: {*****}
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid endpoint address
        
        22:52:03
        (93d185c7-e216-11e8-b175-1b52888bceba) Method completed with status: 500

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you kindly check if you have entered a valid URL in the "Integration Request" section in your API Gateway console? 
This error usually occurs if you integrate API Gateway with a broken HTTP URL in the backend.

Comment: My kubernetes ingress load balancer is public to outside, Do I need to create a VPC link with aws load balancer of nlb type? I am thinking that may be causing issue url looks good to me.In the url I do have query params I'm sending them through request params.